# Abbreviation expander for a given lexicon

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to write a program that will allows users to make short blog entries by typing abbreviations for common words. On completion of the input, Program will expand the abbreviations according to the lexicon defined.

> Conditions

1. A substituted word must be the shortest word that can be formed by adding zero or more letters (or punctuation symbols) to the abbreviation.
2. If two or more unique words can be formed by adding the same number of letters, then the abbreviation should be printed as it is.

> Input

The input is divided into two sections.
The first section is the lexicon itself, and the second section is a user's blog entry that needs to be expanded. The sections are divided by a single | character.

For example:-

cream chocolate every ever does do ice is fried friend friends lick like floor favor flavor flower best but probably poorly say says that what white our you your strawberry storyboard the | wht flvr ic crm ds yr bst fnd lke? ur frds lk stbry, bt choc s prly th bs flr vr!

> Output

what flavor ice cream does your best friend like? our friends lk strawberry, but chocolate is poorly the best floor ever!

I have written the program for this and tested it locally with many different test cases with success but it fails on submission to test server.

An automated Test suit runs to validate the program’s output on its submission to test server. In case of failure, details of the failing test case/cases are not visible.

Below is the program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class BlogEntry {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[][] info = readInput();
        String[] output = inputExpander(info[0],info[1]);
        //System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < output.length; ++i)  {
            if(i!=0)
                System.out.print(" ");

            System.out.print(output[i]);
        }
    }
    public static String[][] readInput() {
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        String input = null;
        String[][] info = new String[2][];
        String[] text;
        String[] abbr;
        try {
            input = bufferReader.readLine();
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(input, "|");
            String first = "", second = "";
            int count = 0;
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                ++count;
                if(count == 1)
                    first  = st1.nextToken();
                if(count == 2)
                    second = st1.nextToken();
            }
            st1 = new StringTokenizer(first, " ");
            count = st1.countTokens();
            text = new String[count];
            count = 0;
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                text[count] = st1.nextToken();
                count++;
            }

            st1 = new StringTokenizer(second, " ");
            count = st1.countTokens();
            abbr = new String[count];
            count = 0;
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                abbr[count] = st1.nextToken();
                count++;
            }
            info[0] = text;
            info[1] = abbr;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return info;
    }
    public static String[] inputExpander(String[] text, String[] abbr) {
        String[] output = new String[abbr.length];

        boolean result;
        for (int i = 0; i < abbr.length; ++i) {
            String abbrToken = abbr[i];
            char[] char_abbr_token = abbrToken.toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < text.length; ++j) {
                String textToken = text[j];
                boolean flag2 = false;
                if ((char_abbr_token[char_abbr_token.length - 1] == '!')
                        || (char_abbr_token[char_abbr_token.length - 1] == '?')
                        || (char_abbr_token[char_abbr_token.length - 1] == ',')
                        || (char_abbr_token[char_abbr_token.length - 1] == ';')) {
                    flag2 = true;
                }
                char[] char_text_token = textToken.toCharArray();
                result = ifcontains(char_text_token, char_abbr_token);
                if (result) {
                    int currentCount = textToken.length();
                    int alreadyStoredCount = 0;

                    if (flag2)
                        textToken = textToken
                                + char_abbr_token[char_abbr_token.length - 1];

                    if (output[i] == null)
                        output[i] = textToken;
                    else {
                        alreadyStoredCount = output[i].length();
                        char[] char_stored_token = output[i].toCharArray();
                        if ((char_stored_token[char_stored_token.length - 1] == '!')
                                || (char_stored_token[char_stored_token.length - 1] == '?')
                                || (char_stored_token[char_stored_token.length - 1] == ',')
                                || (char_stored_token[char_stored_token.length - 1] == ';')) {
                            alreadyStoredCount -= 1;
                        }
                        if (alreadyStoredCount > currentCount) {
                            output[i] = textToken;
                        } else if (alreadyStoredCount == currentCount) {
                            output[i] = abbrToken;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(output[i] == null)
                output[i] = abbrToken;
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static boolean ifcontains(char[] char_text_token,
                                     char[] char_abbr_token) {
        int j = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < char_abbr_token.length; ++i) {
            flag = false;
            for (; j < char_text_token.length; ++j) {
                if ((char_abbr_token[i] == '!') || (char_abbr_token[i] == '?')
                        || (char_abbr_token[i] == ',')
                        || (char_abbr_token[i] == ';')) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (char_abbr_token[i] == char_text_token[j]) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!flag)
                return flag;
        }
        //System.out.println("match found" + flag);
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Can someone direct/hint me to/about the possible use case which I may have missed in the implementation?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not dowvote but I can understand why people downvoted. This is a programming challenge task, the only value to future readers will be a working solution - which is basically cheating.

Comment: Also your code seems to handle symbols like `!`, `?`, `,`, `;`, but there's no description about this case.

Comment: @lexicore Thanks. MY approach is 1) To parse the input (ReadInput method) and store it into 2D array.1st Row for Lexicon and 2nd for abbreviation 2) I pass this info inputExpander which actually expands the abbreviation by iterating over Lexicon and matching(calls ifcontains for matching) and storing the matching word. 3) ifcontains method is responsible for matching logic.

Comment: The characters !,?,,,: can appear at the end of abbreviation word(as mentioned in conditions and sample input).These are to be added to the corresponding expanded word. My approach is almost same as you suggested except for the  matching logic where I have written my own method.

Comment: @Engineer Can a word appear more than once in the lexicon ?

Comment: @Developer Yes.

Comment: @Developer I think this use case needs handling. Thanks Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran your program with duplicate word in input (lexicon). When a word is repeated in the lexicon, it is not getting expanded because the check is only on the length(line no. 112) of the stored word not its content.

I think you need to check:-

1. If same word appears more than once then expand.
2. If 2 or more unique words of same length appear then keep it short.

Answer (score 0):

How would I approach solving this:

- Parse the input, tokenize the lexicon and the text.
- For each (possibly abbreviated) token like `choc` convert it to a regular expression like `.*c.*h.*o.*c.*`.
- Search for shortest lexicon words matching this regular expression. Replace the text token if exactly one is found, otherwise leave it alone.

It is quite hard to say what's wrong with your code without careful debugging. It is hard to understand what one or the other part of the code does, it's not quite self-evident.